# Photon Shot Noise and an Ideal Photodiode and Ideal Transimpedance Amplifier

Tags: noise, photodiode

Light hits an noiseless photodiode and transimpedance amplifier. The light has photon shot noise. If it is relevant, lets say that the light is monochromatic. The photodiode, amplifier, and any optics create enough gain to observe and characterize the photon shot noise. We want to predict the power spectral density of the noise at the output of the transimpedance amplifier.

On one hand, photon shot noise has a poisson probability distribution function. On the other hand, a probability distribution function of noise tells us nothing about the power spectral density of the noise.

Is the photon shot noise like flicker noise, having a 1/f component or is it like white noise and constant over electrical frequency.

Comment: You should ask on physics, but I would assume white.

Comment: Shot noise is white. But if you are looking at very low levels of photon flux, then you have another source of noise -- boson flocking. Just be aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot noise is white i.e. constant power spectral density over frequency (assuming the power of the light generating it is constant)